# Why docusign does not reflecting/giving weird behaviour?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using Docusign for sending some document to sign by User.

I've created some templates and I'm prefilled some data before sending the documents for signing.

When I, modify the templates from docusign New web interface. I am facing some weird behaviour like my pre filled data is gone completely. After some time it comes again.

I don't know what to do with this.

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that you're having these issues. Are you using the DocuSign API or SDKs?

From your question, it sounds like you're using the DocuSign web tool, the NDSE (New DocuSign Signing Experience). For questions on the web tool, please use either the [customer support department](https://support.docusign.com/) or the [customer forum](https://support.docusign.com/forum).

Thank you.